# SwiftUI / Firebase: Can I send and receive a single value to Firebase Database using @Published?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui, observedobject

I'd like to get the current count to update to my Firebase.

I'm making a basic tally counter that I'd like to be able to update in real-time(ish) across devices.

Firebase Authentication already configured & linked to the app.

```swift
  class CurrentCount: ObservableObject {
  @Published var count = 0 }

  struct HomeScreen : View {

  @ObservedObject var UserCount = CurrentCount()

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      
      VStack {
        
        Button(action: {
          self.UserCount.count -= 1
        }) {
          Image(systemName: "minus")
            .foregroundColor(Color("Color"))
            .scaleEffect(2)
            .padding()
            .frame(minWidth:1000, maxWidth: 1000)
            .frame(minHeight:450, maxHeight: 450)
        }
        
          Button(action: {

          }) {
            Text("\(UserCount.count)")
              .foregroundColor(Color("Color"))
              .font(.system(size: 100))
              .padding()
              .onLongPressGesture {
                self.UserCount.count = 0
            }
          }
        }
      
        Button(action: {
          self.UserCount.count += 1
        }) {
          Image(systemName: "plus")
            .foregroundColor(Color("Color"))
            .scaleEffect(2)
            .padding()
            .frame(minWidth:1000, maxWidth: 1000)
            .frame(minHeight:450, maxHeight: 450)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Image of View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UY8I.jpg)

Comment: Do you already know how to send/receive data from Firebase and are just looking for the connection to SwiftUI or do you need the Firebase-related code, too?

Comment: I'm familiar with the process but I wouldn't say that I know. Hoping to get a nudge in the right direction. 

My ideal outcome would be for the $count to be updated for each action, but I'm not sure how to trigger this. Please forgive my amateur vocabulary. I have trawled the internet but a load of the tutorials are quite complex.

Comment: Check out this Firebase Extension: it might be just what you need: https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/firestore-counter. There is an iOS client for it as well: https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-counter/clients/ios/Sources/FirestoreCounter/FirestoreCounter.swift

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be well off to create a helper function in your `ObservableObject` that gets called from your button. In that same object, you can set up a listener for real time updates in your init so that you get notified any time anything changes (note that in the event that your app is the only thing changing the data and you aren't listening from outside sources, you could avoid doing the real-time update and just get the first initial value in init):

```
class CurrentCount: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count = 0
    
    init() {
        //connect to Firebase here and listen for real-time updates: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events
    }
    
    func updateCount(newCount: Int) {
        count = newCount
        //send the value to Firebase here as well
        //https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#basic_write
    }
}
```

To get more information about the details of getting/setting information in Firebase,