# How to get a single document infromation on firestore database?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to get the String value in Users collection/uid/collection of user info. In this path, I tried to have the username info but I couldn't. Is there any way to have single string in specific document?

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
struct ProfileView: View {
    
    @State var logOutActive = false
    @State private var isPresented = false
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var currentUser = Firebase.Auth.auth().currentUser
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
            
        VStack{
            Text(db.collection("Users").document(currentUser!.uid).collection("Username")).font(.custom("Gilroy Semibold", size: 22)).tracking(-0.66)
                
            Button {
                do { try Auth.auth().signOut() }
                   catch { print("already logged out") }

                    logOutActive = true
                if logOutActive == true {
                    isPresented = true
                }
                
            } label: {
                Text("Log Out")
            }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented, content: SignInView.init)
        }
            
            
        }
        
    }
    }


struct ProfileView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProfileView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do an asynchronous Firebase call inside a `View` element like a `Text`. Instead, you should do the async work inside an ObservableObject and then set a `@Published` property when the result comes back.

Comment: @jnpdx Uhm if it does not take a lot of ur time can u please show me? if u cant that totally okay :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68139318/560942 https://stackoverflow.com/a/66695683/560942 https://stackoverflow.com/a/66105447/560942 Those should give you some ideas